# How to find the invisible box around words in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I have received a word document with lots of formatting including columns of text and bullets. When I make modifications to the documents, sometimes the text wraps around within the invisible box such text is contained within.

I would like to know, what can I do to make such invisible boxes around portions of text appear so that I may drag such boxes' handles so as to stretch it so that the words contained therein fit on the same line horizontally even after the modificaiton?

---

EDIT: I have tried going to `Word application icon` -> `Word Options` -> `Advanced` -> `Show text boundaries`. This displays the text boundaries around portions of text, but I still cannnot figure out how to resize these. Any ideas?

Comment: [How to show or hide text boundaries in Word?](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/945-word-show-hide-text-boundaries.html)

Comment: I've updated my post to reflect your suggestion but still no luck. What else should I try? Thanks.

Comment: [Finding an Invisible Text Box](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T010074_Finding_an_Invisible_Text_Box.html)

Comment: I've tried it. When I end the selection the whole page disappears.

Comment: No more ideas. :/

Comment: Thank you for your help... but I'm not sure what to do now...

Comment: Maybe the text is in in a table? [Show or hide gridlines for all tables in a document](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Show-or-hide-gridlines-for-all-tables-in-a-document-84780485-af90-49b1-82a0-682cd7fc9dad)

Comment: Looks like you may have to share your document to get any more tips ffrom anybody ...

Comment: How can I share my document?

Comment: googledocs, dropbox or similar? I won't be able to look at it because I don't have Word installed (I use libreoffice) but others might be able to help. Make sure, of course, that you strip out any personal information before you do so.

Comment: Edit your document to include just the problem page.

Comment: [10 file-sharing options: Dropbox, Google Drive and more](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2505487/web-apps/web-apps-10-file-sharing-options-dropbox-google-drive-and-more.html)